# Why is Mathematica saying this sequence tends to $0$?

Tags: numerics, error-tracking

I am a complete novice in Mathematica so please bear with me. I am trying to graph a sequence that converges to $\pi$ but after $27$ iterations Mathematica just goes crazy and I am not sure why. I got the sequence by first noticing $2^n\sin\frac{\pi}{2^n} \to \pi$ and then just using the double angle formula for cosine. Could some one point out why after 28 iterations Mathematica spits out 0? Also what would be a reasonable way to find how fast by approach converges to pi? Using mathematica? I used Discrete plot but it is hard do see what the error is. I also do not know which tag to use to i apologize if I got it wrong.

Code:

```
a[n_] := a[n] = Sqrt[2 + a[n - 1]];
a[1] = Sqrt[2];

DiscretePlot[2^n  Sqrt[1 - (2 + a[n - 2])/4], {n, 0, 30}]
```

Comment: a[n] convergs to 2. So (2+a[n])/4 is converging to 1. So Sqrt[1-(2+a[n])/4] is converging to Sqrt[1-1]=0.

Comment: Change the plotting range `DiscretePlot[2^n Sqrt[1 - (2 + a[n - 2])/4], {n, 3, 30}]` because `a[i]` is only defined for `ì>=1`

Comment: @bills That is correct, but then how do I increase accuracy? Should I move the $2^n$ into the square root?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You are right, but that did not fix the issue

Comment: Simply specify e.g.; WorkingPrecision -> 100

Comment: @DanielHuber That did the trick, thank you !

Comment: `a[n]` equal to `2 Cos[π/2^(n + 1)]`

Comment: Fun! Try `RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == Sqrt[2 + a[n - 1]], a[1] == Sqrt[2]}, a, {n, 1, 27}]`